# How to organize Bundles in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle

We're developing an e-commerce application with Symfony2. It will have different features like product, sales, customer, shipping management, etc..

And it will have 3 subsystems: Web Frontend, Admin and a RESTful API.

Should we organize our bundles by features or by subsystems?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's your choice! Traditionally, if you explore the vendor bundles that Symfony comes with and the 3rd-party bundles that are available, they are organized by feature.

For example, the [Sonata Project](http://sonata-project.org/) starts with a core bundle and provides features in each of the other bundles.

What you should be more concerned about when splitting your system up into bundles is finding a way to de-couple them from the other bundles so that they can be re-used in other projects with minimal modification but more configuration instead! Your best approach (just an opinion of course) will be to make all of these features individually in the bundles and tie them all together with another bundle.

You may find that answers will become subjective depending on each developer's view on the matter.

Comment: I might have misunderstood his use of the word "features". The way he presents the question, makes me think that he's considering to create a bundle per Entity. He mentions things like `products`, `sales`, and `customer` as features.

Comment: So if bundles are organized by features, this means my routes will direct to the appropriate bundles.. How did Sylius organize their bundles if you know..?

Comment: @chronorep You could [download their bundle yourself and find out!](http://sylius.org/get-started)

Comment: our goal is to completely decouple the view. should we create a bundle whose task is to simple return the templates (more like a repository of views).. or rather should we code the interface into a different application altogether ..the view in turn communicates with our symfony application using an api

Comment: @chronorep [This may be of helpful information to you](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc)

Comment: @sjagr Big thanks for your comment! Sonata is awsome!!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

We've developed an e-commerce solution with Sf2 and at the beginning we asked ourselves the very same questions. Should we organize our bundles around entities or sub-systems(admin, front …) ?

We decided to go for the features/entities solution and we embedded the sub-system in the bundle.

What made us take this decision is the possibility to attach functionalities to the core feature.

For instance, we created bundles like product, catalogs, order, customer … these are the basic bundles that you will find in any e-commerce solution. We also implemented a core bundle that ties them up.

But some of our client may want to use more functionnalities/plugins like tracking, assets/images, reporting. 
These bundles are optional and if we give our client the code of the application, I don't want him to get the code of unwanted/unpaid plugins. So the features are split up in different bundles and they're linked by interfaces and config files.
The bundles also carry the sub-system applications like the administration panel. If the client does not have the tracking bundle, then the administration panel will not show the tracking interface because it is not activated in the kernel.

I hope this will help you make you mind.

Answer (score 1):

Per [symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) you can organize bundles in any way you see fit. So long you stick to the coding convention, and overall good coding practices. Especially if you plan to release this bundle to the public (which might not be the case in this scenario).

That said, I would advice against organizing your project by features because the number of features will always increase over time; whereas the number of subsystems in your project is more than likely to remain constant.

Take in consideration that a new bundle, is a new sub-project to manage, if you're using other bundles or libraries like Assetic, then you would need to enable every single bundle in the configuration, so the bigger the number of bundles, the more difficult it is to manage the overall project.

So, if I were in your position, I would break up the system in subsystems. Create a bundle that exposes a RESTful API, another for the Admin, and another for the Front-end.

Structure them in a way that every bundle can live on their own, just in case you need to deploy every sub-system of your project to different servers, so that is just as easy as striping them out of the main project, and integrate them into a new one.

Comment: I'm just intrigued with the API. Should it be a separate bundle by itself? If yes, then I need to generate a different set of controllers for it. Or could I just reuse the controllers of the other subsystem..   where I can define routes that will allow me to render the result in a different format.